# Combinational logic design question, what does it mean for input to be asserted

Tags: logic

The question reads: consider a 4-input boolean function that is asserted whenever exactly two of its inputs are asserted, construct its truth table, and then other parts for the question.

I don't want an answer i would like to solve this myself, i just want to know the meaning of assert and how to start with the truth table. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that in this context it means true (so you have 4 booleans and you must produce true when exactly 2 are true). Your textbook should make more sense of the issue. Usually you assert that something is true.

Edit. Here's a 3 variable example for `Conjunctive normal form`. I'm considering the function true whenever two of them are false. Notice how by reading the variables horizontally and then vertically you get the binary representation of numbers.

```
     1   2    3   R      
L1   0   0    0   0
L2   0   0    1   1
L3   0   1    0   1
L4   0   1    1   0
L5   1   0    0   1
L6   1   0    1   0
L7   1   1    0   0
L8   1   1    1   0
```

The theory is that you treat each line as a separate equation. If the variable value is 0, you write it as `v`, and if it is 1 you write it as `~v`. You use the logical or (`\/`) between variables on one line, and logican and (`^`) between different lines. You only and together lines which are false.

So, considering column 1 - `p`, column 2 - `q` and column 3 - `r`, the first line is `p \/ q \/ r` and the result is false, so it is added to the final formula, the second one `p \/ q \/ ~r` but true so not added to the formula etc. You need to `and` (`^`) the lines together if and only if the formula for the line is false. So above, you would get the CNF by and-ing together lines L1, L4, L6, L7, L8. Once you have that gigantic formula, you can work on making it smaller.

It's been so long since I've done this I can't really remember the details as to why it is like this but I remember studying the proof at some point.

Comment: so whenever two of the inputs are (1) no matter which ones, the output should be 1? that's what i thought but then why wouldn't they say the output is true when two of the inputs are? or is that just me over-thinking the problem?

Comment: The textbook and you are saying the same thing but with different words.  The word "assert" is found frequently in descriptions of digital electronics: "to request an interrupt, the peripheral asserts the IRQ line.  Whenever the IRQ line is asserted, the CPU..."  The advantage of assert over true in this context is that assert is a transitive verb, making for terser logic descriptions.

Comment: That's true, the result is (1) whenever any two of the inputs are (1). There's a very simple way to solve this, I'll look up my old logic courses and edit the answer with a small example

Comment: To supplement this answer, see definition #4 for *assert* here:  http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assert

Comment: i will consider it as true as you mentioned, thank you :) an example would be great laura, thank you so much!

Comment: I've looked it up in my old courses - this is a textbook example of determining `Conjunctive normal form` - you probably have it in your textbook so I won't edit the answer as it is really simple to go from the truth table to the formula.

Answer (score 3):

The other half of the question is the truth table.  I'll help start that...

```
1 2 3 4    output
F F F F    F
F F F T    F
F F T F    F
F F T T    T
F T F F    F
F T F T    T
. . .
```

Comment: The challenge isn't in the truth table; it's in finding a short way to represent it.